# Collection is not a function when writing new document to Firestore Database collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create a new document with a custom ID under an existing collection named, "boxingvids" in a Firestore Database using nodejs. This is the code I have written:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { getFirestore, doc, set, collection} = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

    app.post('/database', async (req, res) => {
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
        });
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const collectionRef = db.collection('boxingvids');
        const docRef = collection(db, 'testing');
        docRef.set(docRef, {
            vidKey: 'testing',
            footWork: 4
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Document successfully written!')
            res.json({ message: req.body })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
        });
    });
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'boxingvids');
                          ^

TypeError: collection is not a function
```

Would appreciate help in resolving this issue.

Comment: I'm kinda confused with your error and written code. It seems like you switch collectionRef and docRef. However, you may try this: `const docRef = collectionRef.doc('testing');` // for document reference